# Trouble Pasting Entire Row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to paste the enire row of information to the next available row but I keep getting errors about not having the `Rows(lastrow +1, 1).EntireRow.Paste` written correctly. Please let me know how I can perform that action correctly.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myValue As String
    myEmp = InputBox("Search for an employee by last name")
    Range("B3").Value = myEmp

With Sheet7
    Range("B:B").Select
        Set Row = Selection.Find(What:=myEmp, After:=ActiveCell, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Row.EntireRow.Copy

End With

Worksheets("Employee Reports").Activate
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Rows(lastrow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Paste


End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A4:A20").Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: `Rows(lastrow + 1, 1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial`

Comment: When I run that, I get run-time error '1004': application-defined or object defined error for that line

Comment: When I did that, it gave me Run-time error '438': object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: `Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myValue As String
    myEmp = InputBox("Search for an employee by last name")
    ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value = myEmp

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Worksheets("Employee Reports").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    With Sheet7
        Dim rw As Range
        Set rw = .Range("B:B").Find(What:=myEmp, After:=.Range("B1"), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not rw Is Nothing Then
            rw.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Employee Reports").Cells(lastrow + 1, 1)
        Else
            MsgBox myEmp & " Not Found in Range"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I copied and pasted that, and now I get run-time error '9': Subscript out of range for `lastrow = Worksheets("Employee Reports").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @Tara then there is no sheet named `Employee Reports`  Check to make sure it is spelled correctly and there are no preceding or end spaces in the sheet name.

Comment: Yep you were right, small typo. Now it gives run-type error '13': Type mismatch for `Set rw = .Range("B:B").Find(What:=myEmp, After:=ActiveCell, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)`

Comment: Going to remove my answer as Scott hit on the 2 things I was working with... inappropriate syntax (swapped to using `Cells()`) and copy/paste directly one after another to prevent the clipboard from clearing the Copy.

Comment: @ScottCraner I also just saw your comment about the `.paste` and missed the change to `.pastespecial` when answering

Comment: Hey guys, do you know how I could edit the code to make it paste every time the row is found with that person's name? Right now it's only copying and pasting the first row it finds and not all rows